# Given a git refname, can I detect whether it's a hash, tag, or branch?

Tags: git

I'm writing a script that will take in a specification used as the base for creating a branch. Thus, it will have something like this:

```
git checkout -b $newbranch $startingpoint
```

Now, `startingpoint` can be specified either as a branch name, a tag, or a SHA1.

Later in the script, I need to do different things based on what `startingpoint` actually is.  Is had thought `git rev-parse` would give me this information, but I cannot seem to bend it to my whim.

Is there a git way, preferably a porcelain, to get the information I seek?

**Update**

I used the `show-ref` information to craft the following shell function:

```
git_ref_type() {
    [ -n "$1" ] || die "Missing ref name"

    if git show-ref -q --verify "refs/heads/$1" 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "branch"
    elif git show-ref -q --verify "refs/tags/$1" 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "tag"
    elif git show-ref -q --verify "refs/remote/$1" 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "remote"
    elif git rev-parse --verify "$1^{commit}" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "hash"
    else
        echo "unknown"
    fi
    return 0
}
```

This seems to work well for now, though it's been only very lightly tested.

Comment: `git cat-file -t <object>` can tell you whether a Git object is a commit or some other type of object, but I'm not sure about branches vs tags. See more info at [git-cat-file(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cat-file.html) and [Git Internals - Git Objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).

Comment: `git cat-file -t <thing>` will return `commit` for branches, tags, and commits (because they all reference the same thing).  `git show-ref` will tell you what kind of reference you're dealing with.

Comment: Also note that you might occasionally run into a name that is both a branch and a tag, for example. While naming a branch and a tag (and a remote, even) all with the same name could be confusing to users who don't pay close attention, and so it might not be a great idea, `git` doesn't do anything to prevent it...

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the branch/tag same-name. I've actually run into that before. In my case what matters is which one checkout chooses--does it prefer a branch or a tag when selecting the base?

Comment: A quick look at the docs seems to indicate this isn't extremely well documented, but I probably missed something. My understanding, though, is that `git checkout` tries, in this order, 1) a local branch with that name, 2) a remote branch with that name, but only if it's unambiguous (only one remote with that branch), 3) a tag. There are probably some other subtleties involved, but that's the basic outline...

Comment: In that case, the order I have in the code snippet above is close to correct, and certainly correct enough for my needs. Thanks!

Comment: Note that git 1.8.5 or 1.9 (Q4 2014) will add `git rev-parse --verify v1.0^{tag}` as a way to test if `v1.0` is a tag, consistent with `v1.0^{commit/tree/blob}`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18961431/6309)

Comment: @larsks, `git cat-file -t <thing>` returns `commit` for branches and commits, but not for tags. For tags it returns `tag`.

Comment: Not quite.  `git cat-file -t <ref>` returns _commit_ for branches, commits, and lightweight tags; and returns _tag_ for annotated tags.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can probably use the `show-ref` command to do (mostly) what you want.  Given some string, if it refers to a tag then...

```
git show-ref --verify refs/tags/$thestring
```

...will be true.  If it's a branch name, then...

```
git show-ref --verify refs/heads/$thestring
```

...will be true.  If the string fails both of those tests, then...

```
git rev-parse --verify "$thestring^{commit}"
```

...will tell you if it otherwise refers to a commit (which could be a complete SHA1, a partial SHA1, `HEAD`, or possibly something else that doesn't fall into the previous two categories.

Comment: I think this takes me down the path I want. In the motivating case, I think what I really need to distinguish is between a branch...and anything else (since a tag is just a name for a specific commit). So, the <code>show-ref --verify refs/heads/$thestring</code> should get me what I need.  I'll try it and see.

Answer (score 9):

Note that [git 1.8.5 or 1.9 (Q4 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/128a96c98442524c7f2eeef4757b1e48445f24ce/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.txt#L100-L102) will provide for a new way to test if a ref is a tag or not.

> Make "`foo^{tag}`" to peel a tag to itself, i.e. no-op., and fail if "`foo`" is not a tag.

#### How to test a [revision](https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/Documentation/revisions.txt) is a tag? (or "check if a git name is a tag"?)

```
git rev-parse --verify v1.0^{tag}
```

More convenient than: `test $(git cat-file -t v1.0) = tag`".

See commits [75aa26d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75aa26d34c4a80142512bd980a416b0fb30044c1) and [abdb54a1d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/abdb54a1d26c79692468aaf2c651e85c2a917c15), by [Richard Hansen](http://www.ir.bbn.com/%7Erhansen/):

#### peel_onion(): add support for `<rev>^{tag}`

> Complete the `<rev>^{<type>}` family of object descriptors by having `<rev>^{tag}` dereference `<rev>` until a tag object is found (or fail if unable).

> At first glance this may not seem very useful, as commits, trees, and blobs cannot be peeled to a tag, and a tag would just peel to itself.
> However, this can be used to ensure that `<rev>` names a tag object:
>
> ```
> $ git rev-parse --verify v1.8.4^{tag}
> 04f013d
> $ git rev-parse --verify master^{tag}
> error: master^{tag}: expected tag type, but the object dereferences to tree type
> fatal: Needed a single revision
> ```
>
> Users can already ensure that `<rev>` is a tag object by checking the output of '`git cat-file -t <rev>`', but:
>
> - users may expect `<rev>^{tag}` to exist given that `<rev>^{commit}`, `<rev>^{tree}`, and `<rev>^{blob}` all exist
> - this syntax is more convenient/natural in some circumstances

However, as mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222634/given-a-git-refname-can-i-detect-whether-its-a-hash-tag-or-branch/18961431#comment120217615_18961431) by [mtraceur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4372452/mtraceur), that would not work for a *lightweight* tag (see "[creating tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#_creating_tags)"), which is just name a for an object (usually a commit object).

You would get an error like:

> Eexpected tag type, but the object dereferences to tree type

Because, with a lightweight tag, would would be actually parsing a commit, instead of an actual tag.
From "[Git Internals - Git References](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References)":

[image: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/images/data-model-4.png]

If you make a lightweight tag on a commit, git rev-parse ^{tag} would actually parsing and dereferencing the commit itself, not the tag.

Comment: "users may expect <rev>^{tag}..."---yes!  this user certainly did! Thanks for the followup on this question. I'll look forward to grabbing 1.8.5 when it lands and packaging it for our company's internal use.

Comment: This only seems to work for annotated tags, and not lightweight tags.

Comment: @SteveFolly That seems expected, since only an annotated tag can be dereferenced. A lightweight tag is applied directly on the object.

Comment: @VonC While that might be expected for someone who thinks in terms of git internals like objects, for someone who thinks in terms of higher-level user-facing abstracted concepts like "tags", it is extremely counter-intuitive. I keep seeing errors like "expected tag type, but the object dereferences to tree type" and I'm guessing this lightweight tag problem is the reason, but is it even documented anywhere?

Comment: @mtraceur It comes from https://github.com/git/git/commit/5385f52da80be0d01fda45be586eb186c2be83ee, so the very beginning of Git itself. Documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emltrevgtltngtemegemHEADmaster3em

Comment: @VonC Duuude, what does that have to do with what I'm saying? I'm telling you it's not obvious to anyone who doesn't understand git's low-level concepts. You pointed me at 1) a commit which is changing and discussing git's implementation, and 2) documentation where the only relevant sentence is "<rev>^{tag} can be used to ensure that <rev> identifies an existing tag object", which does not mention lightweight tags and is thus completely opaque to anyone who does not already know git enough to know that lightweight tags are not tag _objects_ or whatever.

Comment: Consider that many (maybe even the majority) `git` users barely understand what a git "object" is, or the distinction between lightweight tags and other tags. Just because those details have been around since the beginning of git doesn't mean they're familiar to the average git user who might come across this answer. They are low-level details, almost so much so that I think it's fair to call them "internals", except in-so-far as git does not abstract most internals away from users at all.

Comment: All I'm trying to say is that this answer could be improved by explicitly saying that  `^{tag}` does not work for lightweight tags. Because I guarantee you there are going to be a lot of readers who are not familiar enough with how git works to even think of the possibility that some tags are different than others, or to think that the different kinds of tags might be different in a way that is relevant in this case.

Comment: Got it, thank you for the feedback. I am on my phone right now, I will edit the answer this afternoon.